# Request.Form Question

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is an aspx page in the project. And one line is below;

```
value = Request.Form("xxx")
```

How can I learn where post is coming? From which page the post is coming?

Comment: where do you have that line? In which method of the web form?

Comment: in the page load of the page, it's coded for getting the "xxx" value.

Comment: Why don't you know the page inside of the page load of the page?  Is it a master page, are you actually in a control, are you doing cross-page postback, or maybe making some sort of ajax postback to an aspx page?

Comment: you can be right, I dont know how to control it, so I ask the question :)

Comment: I wasn't suggesting an answer I was trying to understand what you are trying to do.  I see you selected an answer below so I assume you wanted to know what control the post data came from.

Answer (score 1):

in the `Page_Load` you can check the current handler if not post back, see here:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                var currentRequest = HttpContext.Current.Handler;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if you debug this you will see the value of the `currentRequest` object, it's the calling page and if you come to a webform with a `Server.Transfer` or `Response.Redirect` this is the usual way to grab some data from the calling webform.

as in other answer, of course, anytime, you can and should check the properties of the `Request` object, like `RawUrl` and so on... :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  if(IsPostBack)

       {

             Label1.Text=Global.GetPostBackControl(this).ID.ToString();

       }
```

Comment: Global.GetPostBackControl isn't something built in.  I assume your it came from something like this https://evacion.wordpress.com/tag/source-of-a-postback.  Either way the OP appears to be looking for the page that did the post not the control on the current page.

Comment: @drs9222 : sorry the url you posted is not valid

Comment: @drs9222 : yes i managed to open it and i agree with you the code is looking for the control

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx)
you should find the information in [Request.RawUrl Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the debugger stopped at that line, and the page where the line `value=Request.Form("xxx")"` (note: this looks more like VB to me) resides is `Page1.aspx`, then
you could search your entire project/solution for something along these lines

`action\s*=\s*['"].*Page1.*>` using for example visual studio's Find (Ctrl+F) and checking Use:RegularExpression

Edit: this will try to find the form that posts to the page using the form's action attribute